# Parsing data from app.config to WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, app-config

I have app.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="KEY_1" value="VALUE_1,VALUE_2" />
  <add key="KEY_2" value="VALUE_1,VALUE_2" />   
</appSettings>
```

I need to read data to the `ListBox` where item names will be `KEY_1`, `KEY_2`... When I select an item from the `LIstBox`, the `TextBox`'es are filled with `VALUE_1` and `VALUE_2`.

How to do it?

I think, i will make loop like:

```
var appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
  for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.Count; i++)
```

But how to add this data to the `ListBox`, while also filling TextBox'es?

Comment: What `ListBox` and `TextBox`? Please show them.

Comment: @blins, https://i.imgur.com/Vsin1Fz.png
```<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="65" Width="100"/>
<ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem"/>
</ListBox>```